# In IE new window is opening instead of new tab in selenium web driver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

When a link is clicked manually in my application, it opens in new tab in Chrome and IE.However when my script is run, the link opens in a new window in IE instead of new tab. Same script runs as expected in Chrome. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: what's the ie version

Comment: Its IE 10 and my application is supposed to support that version. Application is running fine manually in this version.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Click instead of normal click

Answer (score 2):

Change the default settings of your IE.

1. Open Internet Explorer, click the Tools icon (or press Ctrl-X), and then click Internet Options.
2. In the General tab, find the Tabs section, then click the Settings button within that section.
3. Midway down that Settings dialog, there's an option called "When a new tab is opened, open:"—and a pull-down menu below it.
4. Click that pull-down, then choose The new tab page. (Joel's somehow got set to another option: "Your first home page.")
5. Click OK, then OK again.