# C# Selenium - IE 11 - Clicking link opens new window instead of new tab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I'm running a Selenium test in C# to open a URL, log in using a supplied username & password, then navigate to a page containing downloadable reports. See my code below (note: website names and usernames/passwords are withheld):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumProject
{
    class SeleniumTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Constants

            //User Account Information
            const string username = "MyUsername";
            const string password = "MyPassword";

            //Initial Login Page URL and Elements
            const string urlLogin = "MyURL";
            const string usernameLoginName = "username";
            const string passwordLoginName = "password";
            const string submitLoginClassName = "btnAlign";

            //Welcome Page Element
            const string profileWelcomeClassName = "mstrLargeIconViewItemLink";

            #endregion

            int elementListIndex = 0;

            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlLogin);

            driver.FindElement(By.Name(usernameLoginName)).SendKeys(username);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name(passwordLoginName)).SendKeys(password);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(submitLoginClassName)).Click();

            if (driver.Title == "Servicer Performance Profile Home. MicroStrategy")
            {
                try
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(profileWelcomeClassName)).Click();
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
                {
                    //failed
                }
            }

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src,'images/freddiemac/sppdash/navigation-drawer-1.png')]")));

            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> elementList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src,'images/freddiemac/sppdash/navigation-drawer-1.png')]"));

            string mainHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

            foreach (var element in elementList)
            {
                if (element.Displayed && elementListIndex == 5)
                {
                    element.Click();

                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'EDR Overview')]")).Click();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    elementListIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is whenever I execute that last Click() event that's within the if statement nested inside of the foreach loop, instead of the normal behavior of the link opening a new tab in the same IE, it's opening as a new window and reverting back to a prior page. Normally, whenever I log into this website manually and click this link, a new tab is opened that contains another download link inside of it; *that's* the page I'm trying to get to.

I have no idea why this new browser window is opening with a prior page instead of even the target page I'm requesting. Could this have something to do with Selenium & IE11 not getting along? Another idea is the current login session expiring somehow, but this is all being executed in less than 10 seconds, so I wouldn't assume this is the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751758/in-ie-new-window-is-opening-instead-of-new-tab-in-selenium-web-driver

Comment: Tried changing the settings of IE as suggested in the link you provided. My issue continues. Wasn't solved.

Comment: Why are you clicking twice? element.Click(); and                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'EDR Overview')]")).Click();

Comment: Hi, Koen. 

My foreach loop will click the element at index 5 in elementList. Once that is clicked, a div with text of "EDR Overview" is made visible and clicked. Now if I'm performing all of these actions manually (not by code), that second click on the newly visible div opens a new tab with the all-important download link. That download link is the element I'm after and it's the sole reason for doing all of this. When the code is executed, instead of that newly visible div opening a tab with the downloadable link, it's opening a new IE window of an incorrect page. Hopefully that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. After many, many failed attempts at changing IE settings for handling new tabs, executing JavaScript onclick() events programmatically (instead of using native browser click commands), opening and switching between empty tabs, trying right-click keyboard commands, etc., the issue came down to IE simply not being compatible with what I was trying to do. First attempt with Google Chrome proved to be successful. The website behaved normally and links that were supposed to trigger a new tab indeed triggered the new tab.

My advice to those of you new to Selenium webdriver testing, whether your language is C# or something else, is to avoid Internet Explorer at all costs. Even with IE 11, none of what I was wanting to do worked. Test using Chrome as your first choice. Maybe it will save you three working days of troubleshooting and debugging.